# MX Records / DNS settings (mail not received)

Tags: email, dns, domain, plesk

We have a VPS running Plesk and I have the following DNS records set in Plesk DNS manager; specifics have been changed change for privacy. But the  mailbox does not appear to be receiving mail although able to send and there are no delivery failed messages. Can someone perhaps see a problem?

```
212.67.000.000 / 24 PTR mail.MYDOMAIN.com.
_domainkey.MYDOMAIN.com.    TXT o=-
default._domainkey.MYDOMAIN.com.    TXT p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
ftp.MYDOMAIN.com.   CNAME   MYDOMAIN.com.
ipv4.MYDOMAIN.com.  A   212.67.000.000
mail.MYDOMAIN.com.  A   212.67.000.000
ns.MYDOMAIN.com.    A   212.67.000.000
MYDOMAIN.com.   NS  ns.MYDOMAIN.com.
MYDOMAIN.com.   A   212.67.000.000
MYDOMAIN.com.   MX (10) mail.MYDOMAIN.com.
MYDOMAIN.com.   TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
webmail.MYDOMAIN.com.   A   212.67.000.000
www.MYDOMAIN.com.   CNAME   MYDOMAIN.com.
```

Comment: Thanks, all the mx toolbox tests i.e. max test, smtp test, email server test, blacklist check come out positive... im stuck for ideas as to where the emails go!

Comment: If you cant receive a mail you should get a NDR message back when you try to send a e-mail. So what does the NDR message say? Please Post the message here.

Comment: As I said, we dont get any non deliver report or bounce back :(